# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 422: Unprocessable Entity - Python - VS

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

I'm trying to run this code but I end up with urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 422: Unprocessable Entity. It's weird that it won't work for me but to others works fine.

```
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd



ticker = 'AAPL'
period1 = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2008,6,30,23,59).timetuple()))
period2 = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2021,12,31,23,59).timetuple()))
interval = '1m' #1d, 1wk


query_string = f'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1={period1}&period2={period2}&interval={interval}&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true'


df = pd.read_csv(query_string)
#print(df)
df.to_csv('aapl.csv')
#df.to_excel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the interval as below for monthly.

```
interval = '1mo'
```